# decltype(auto) return type not deducible in clang

Tags: c++, clang, c++14, return-type, auto

I'm currently fiddling with composed operations in boost asio and can't understand why clang seems unable to deduce the return type of my `get_executor()` method:

```
template<class Stream, class Resolver, class CompletionToken>
auto resolve_and_connect(
    std::string_view host,
    std::string_view port,
    Stream& stream,
    Resolver& resolver,
    CompletionToken&& token)
{
    using Signature = void(boost::system::error_code);
    using Handler = BOOST_ASIO_HANDLER_TYPE(CompletionToken, Signature);

    auto initiation = [](auto&& completion_handler, Stream& stream, Resolver& resolver) {
        struct intermediate_handler {
            Handler m_handler;
            Stream& m_stream;

            decltype(auto) get_executor() {
                return net::get_associated_executor(m_handler, m_stream.get_executor());
            }
            // using executor_type = decltype(std::declval<intermediate_handler>().get_executor());
        };

        intermediate_handler{completion_handler, stream};
    };

    return net::async_initiate<CompletionToken, Signature>(
        initiation, token, std::ref(stream), std::ref(resolver)
    );
}
```

Fails with:

```
 error: no viable conversion from returned value of type 'typename associated_executor<(lambda at test.cpp:9:71), executor>::type' (aka 'boost::asio::executor') to function return type 'decltype(auto)'
                    return net::get_associated_executor(m_handler, m_stream.get_executor());
                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Compiled with `clang version 10.0.0-4ubuntu1` and `-std=c++17`.

Notice that `namespace net = boost::asio;` is implicit in the above code.

Comment: Have you tried compiling in gcc? Would be interesting to know what its message is.

Comment: @Taekahn interessting: gcc 9.3.0 compiles it just fine

Comment: [Minimal example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/CR0wZb7Mu7Nznsms)

Comment: I know clang has some differences in the way it looks up types, but I don't want to send you down a red herring.  At least we know its clang specific.

Comment: It looks like if you do a decltype of the expression instead of auto it might work. That doesn't explain why, but if that solves your problem, I'd raise it with clang team as an issue. (Though I'm interested in the answer too)

Comment: @Taekahn yeah you're right, that compiles for me. Kind of undermines the point though, especially since `decltype(auto)` is supposed to behave exactly like that.

Comment: Clang bug, already reported https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=32766 but hasn't received much attention :(

Comment: The difference is prompted by the lambda being polymorphic. If you make it take an `int` instead of `auto` it will compile on both GCC and Clang.